# RabbitMQ 'None of the Specified Endpoints were Reachable'

Tags: c#, windows, networking, rabbitmq, centos

Trying to create a connection to RabbitMQ inside a Virtual Machine. My specs are as follow:

RabbitMQ-Host: Windows 10
VirtualMachine: CentOS 7

The rabbitMQ is succesfully installed in the host, the management web page is working perfectly nice and inside the host machine I can succesfully send and retrieve messages.
Using a simple Python connection tester, I can don't receive any errors and the connections appears to be succesfull. Followed tutorial at: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html

The problem is when I try to connect to RabbitMQ via the virtual machine.
Follow all the common fixes:

- Port Access

  - All ports are open. Tried with firewall ON and OFF. curl -v telnet://HOSTNAME:5672 works as intendeed from the CentOS machine
  - curl hostname:15672 returns the index page
- Listeners

  - rabbitmq-diagnostics status returns OK of the node
  - rabbitmq-diagnostics listeners shows my listener on the HOST
- Diagnostics

  - executed "rabbitmq-diagnostics environment" and all seems fine
  - RabbitMQ is not directing any logs from the connection in rabbit.log

Error:

```
None of the specified endpoints were reachable
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String clientProvidedName)
  at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()
  at gennera.server.consumer.RabbitMqConsumer.CreateConnection() in /root/sap-api/Queue/AcademicQueue/gennera.server/consumer/RabbitMqConsumer.cs:line 46
Connection failed
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ConnectOrFail(ITcpClient socket, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, TimeSpan timeout)
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ConnectUsingAddressFamily(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan timeout, AddressFamily family)
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ConnectUsingIPv4(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan timeout)
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler..ctor(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan connectionTimeout, TimeSpan readTimeout, TimeSpan writeTimeout)
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.IProtocolExtensions.CreateFrameHandler(IProtocol protocol, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan connectionTimeout, TimeSpan readTimeout, TimeSpan writeTimeout)
  at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateFrameHandler(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint)
  at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
Connection refused
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.ValueTaskSourceAsTask.<>c.<.cctor>b__4_0(Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.TcpClientAdapter.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port)
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.TaskExtensions.TimeoutAfter(Task task, TimeSpan timeout)
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ConnectOrFail(ITcpClient socket, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, TimeSpan timeout)
Unhandled exception. System.Exception: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
  at gennera.server.consumer.RabbitMqConsumer.CreateConnection() in /root/sap-api/Queue/AcademicQueue/gennera.server/consumer/RabbitMqConsumer.cs:line 61
  at gennera.server.consumer.RabbitMqConsumer..ctor() in /root/sap-api/Queue/AcademicQueue/gennera.server/consumer/RabbitMqConsumer.cs:line 27
  at gennera.server.Worker.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) in /root/sap-api/Queue/AcademicQueue/gennera.server/Worker.cs:line 20
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
  at gennera.server.Program.Main(String[] args) in /root/sap-api/Queue/AcademicQueue/gennera.server/Program.cs:line 12
```

C# code:

```
try
{
    var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory
    {
        HostName = rabbitMqUrl,
        UserName = "gennera",
        Password = "gennera",
        Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort,
        VirtualHost = "/",
        RequestedHeartbeat = new TimeSpan(60),
        Ssl = { ServerName = rabbitMqUrl, Enabled = false }
    };

    return connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("rabbitMqUrl"));
    var tempExcetion = e.InnerException;
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    while (tempExcetion.InnerException != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(tempExcetion.InnerException.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(tempExcetion.InnerException.StackTrace);
        tempExcetion = tempExcetion.InnerException;
    }
    // Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    throw new Exception(e.Message);
}
```

Python Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('gennera', 'gennera')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='192.168.3.2',credentials=credentials))
channel = connection.channel()
print(connection)
print(channel)
```

Python Result:

```
<BlockingConnection impl=<SelectConnection OPEN transport=<pika.adapters.utils.io_services_utils._AsyncPlaintextTransport object at 0x7f55ddf9f1d0> params=<ConnectionParameters host=192.168.3.2 port=5672 virtual_host=/ ssl=False>>>
<BlockingChannel impl=<Channel number=1 OPEN conn=<SelectConnection OPEN transport=<pika.adapters.utils.io_services_utils._AsyncPlaintextTransport object at 0x7f55ddf9f1d0> params=<ConnectionParameters host=192.168.3.2 port=5672 virtual_host=/ ssl=False>>>>
```

Thanks in advance!

------ EDIT ------

Resolved it by changing the code in CreateConnection to:

```
try
{
    var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory
    {
        Uri = new Uri($"amqp://gennera:gennera@{rabbitMqUrl}/"),
        DispatchConsumerAsync = false,
        ConsumerDispatchConcurrency = 1,
    };
```

The properties "DispatchConsumerAsync" and "ConsumerDispatchConcurrency" did the trick.

Comment: Have you checked that the C# code is using the correct URL?

Comment: Yes! It was not the URL.
I solved the problem. Check the EDIT!